# JQuery multiple slideshows with the same previous/next buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to figure out a frustrating issue.

***What I have now :***

- One `ul` containing two `li`, each containing one 3x3 `table`.
- A jQuery "slideshow" script to show one `table` at once.
- Two `div` on each side of the `table` (used for the "slideshow", `prevButton` and `nextButton`).
- Clicking on a `td` "expands" a specific `div` covering the whole 3x3 `table` (`prevButton` and `nextButton` are still visible).
- Clicking on an expanded `div` closes it and the `table` is visible again.
- When no `div` is expanded and the `table` is visible, the `nextButton` and `prevButton` are used to go to the next/previous `table`.

http://jsfiddle.net/m1djrrj8/

***What I'm trying to do :***

- When a `div` is expanded (by clicking on a `td`), the `table` is covered and the `nextButton` and `prevButton` should **NOT** be used to go to the next/previous `table`, but rather be used to show the next/previous expanded `div`.

***Rough structure of the fiddle***

[image]

***Understanding with the Fiddle***

- There are two tables with 9 cells (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I), swap from one to another by clicking on the yellow sidebars.
- Clicking on each cell opens a specific div :

  - (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) displays (sq1,sq2,sq3,sq4,sq5,sq6,sq7,sq8,sq9)
  - (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I) displays (sqA,sqB,sqC,sqD,sqE,sqF,sqG,sqH,sqI).
- when sq1~9 or sqA~I is displayed, I would like to use the yellow sidebars to slideshow sq1 through sq9 **or** sqA through sqI instead of switching tables.

The JSFiddle is a bit long and I apologize for that, but I would be really grateful if someone could help me out with this one; I'm tearing my hair out!

Comment: After 3 looks at your demo and reading all over again your question it's not clear what's covering what, Li, UL TABLE next prev what?

Comment: I have updated the OP adding a picture of how it is structured (had to upload to tinypic, there is a 10 rep restriction to post images, sorry for the trouble), does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

".button" is programmed to swich between `<li>`'s. So when you click the prev button or the next button, the current `<li>` disappears and the other `<li>` appears.
To get the desired result, you have to change the logic:

1. Check if a `<div>` covers the table.
2. If so, hide the `<div>` and show the next `<div>`.